# What is the script to make a Camera follow an object in GODOT?

Tags: graphics, camera, godot

When I apply the script to a camera in GODOT to make the camera follow a vehicle body, what is the code? The code I got [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5vE-nNszxA) is on youtube but in the tutorial the text is too small for me to make out. This is the code I have:

```
extends Camera

export (NodePath) var follow_this_path = null
export var target_distance = 3.0
export var target_height = 2.0

var follow_this = null
var last_lookat

func _ready():
    follow_this = get_node(follow_this_path)
    last_lookat = follow_this.global_transform.origin

func _physics_proceed(delta):
    var delta_v = global_transform.origin - follow_this.global_transform.origin
    var target_pos = global_transform.origin

    # ignore y
    delta_v.y = 0.0

    if (delta_v.length() > target_distance):
        delta_v = delta_v.normalized() + target_distance
        delta_v.y = target_height
        target_pos = follow_this.global_transform.origin + delta_v
    else:
        target_pos.y = follow_this.global_transform.origin.y + target_height

    global_transform.origin = global_transform.origin.linear_interpolate(target_pos, delta + 20.0)

    last_lookat = last_lookat.linear_interpolate(follow_this.global_transform.origin, delta + 20.0)

    look_at(last_lookat, Vector3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, if you set "Current" property in the Camera inspector, it will automatically follow the vehicle, assuming Camera is child of your vehicle.